# How to add comment and spent time in one call to Gitlab API?

Tags: api, gitlab-api

I have two separate calls

```
addSpentTime(projectId, issueIid, duration, date) {
    const endpoint = this.apiUrl(
      `/projects/${projectId}/issues/${issueIid}/notes?body=/spend ${duration} ${date}`
    );
    return this.ajaxRequest("POST", endpoint);
}

addComment(projectId, issueIid, comment) {
    const endpoint = this.apiUrl(
      `/projects/${projectId}/issues/${issueIid}/notes?body=${comment}`
    );
    return this.ajaxRequest("POST", endpoint);
}
```

The first one is for sending how much time has been spent on an issue and the latter is for adding a comment to the issue.

I'd like to do both of these actions in one call like this

```
addSpentTimeAndComment(projectId, issueIid, duration, date, comment) {
    const endpoint = this.apiUrl(
        `/projects/${projectId}/issues/${issueIid}/notes?body=${comment}/spend ${duration} ${date}`
    );
    return this.ajaxRequest("POST", endpoint);
}
```

but the suffix `/spend ${duration} ${date}` makes it into the comment as well. It seems that the API takes literally everything that comes after `body=` as a part of the comment. I tried to add `\n`, `\\n`, spaces, backslashes to signify the end of the comment so that the `/spend` part gets evaluated as well and I also tried changing the order so that the `/spend` is before the comment body but nothing seemed to work. The [GitLab API docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/notes.html#create-new-issue-note) don't mention any standard way of ending the comment or maybe they do but I can't find it anywhere. Furthermore, I don't even know what it's called - delimiter, escaping symbol...?

Is there a way of signifying the ending of the comment, giving a way of appending other commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the comment (project note) call, append the time as a [Quick Action](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/quick_actions.html) using the `/spend <time> call`.

By posting that to the API with the comment, GitLab will add the time at the same time it adds the comment.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I thought that `/spend` was a part of the API. As for the code I posted, I just added `comment += \`\n/spend ${timeExpr} ${date}\`;` before doing `comment = encodeURI(comment);` and used the call from `addComment`.